# Angular directive scope evaluation with function binding ('&')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

We are seeing some unexpected behavior in how a function is being bound to a directive scope. [Here is a jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/zawegobo/5/edit).

To summarize - we have a directive that has a scope object as follows:

```js
scope: { fn: '&', val: '@' }
```

The directive displays the result of `fn` twice. First we display the result as it is evaluated in the template, then we display the result when evaluated in the `link` function:

```html
<div><code>fn (&)</code>: {{fn()}}</div>
<div><code>fn result ($scope.result = $scope.fn()) </code>: {{result}}</div>
```

We then use this scope in another directive:

```js
app.directive('rootDirective', function() {

  function link($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
    $scope.name = 'directive with scope';
  }
  return {
    scope: 'isolate',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link,
    template: [
      '<div add-scope-directive="">',
      '  <div ng-repeat="n in [1]">',
      '    <sub-dir val="{{val}}" fn="fn()" name="{{n}}"></sub-dir>',
      '  </div>',
      '  <sub-dir val="{{val}}" fn="fn()" name="{{name}}"></sub-dir>',
      '<div>'
    ].join('\n')
  };
});
```

On the root node of this directive we have another directive `add-scope-directive`. In this directive we define `fn` - which returns "add-scope-directive - fn".

We would now expect to see that the result of `fn` ("add-scope-directive - fn") to be the same throughout the directive. However the result from the link function of the child directive 'sub-dir' when it is not used in a repeater is different - instead it is coming from the function on the MainCtrl.

The question is - are our expectations correct and is this a bug? Or should we be expecting what we see here and if so why?

Comment: What is `scope: 'isolate'`?

Comment: same as `scope: {}` @link. It looks like initialising the scope in the controller makes the result consistent: [example here](http://jsbin.com/zawegobo/17/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper solution, but a workaround could be to put a timeout into the link function of sub-dir, like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $scope.result = $scope.fn();
  $scope.$apply();
}, 0);
```

Comment: use angular's `$timeout` not setTimeout that way you won't have to use `$scope.$apply()`